# Debug Area Closes in Xcode When Running App

Tags: xcode4

In Xcode 4 the debug area closes every time I run an app, even though I have the debug area open before I hit Run.

Is there anyway to ensure that if I already have the debug area open that it will remain open when I run my app? This would save a lot of time as I wouldn't have to open it back up each time I execute code.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Have a look at `Xcode -> Preferences -> Behaviors`

Here, you can basically tell Xcode to do X when Y happens. You can tell him to hide or show certain areas, to play sounds and show alerts and even to display specified tabs. In your case, there might something like `Testing/Running starts -> hide debugger` be set.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

With Xcode 5.1 I had to go to `Xcode -> Preferences -> Behaviors -> Running -> Completes` and change `If no output, hide` to `Show debugger with Current Views`. Note that I've never changed other behaviors. So, I assume `If no output, hide` is default with this version of Xcode.